# Spotfire OVER function in labels for images

Tags: label, spotfire

I am asking for help with an issue with labels in spotfire for a scatter plot chart. I show images of car's logos on marked rows.

Right now for one point on the chart 5 rows are selected:
- 4 of BMW logos 
- 1 of MERCEDES logo

I would like to be able to group those 4 same logo in one. Kind of a the following expression:

```
[Logo] OVER ( [ program ] )
```

Wanted result:
- 1 Logo BMW
- 1 LOGO MERCEDES

Couldn't find a way to do it, thanks a lot people!

Comment: Well, what's making them separate? What's on your category and value axis? Clearly there is another dimension which is causing 4 to show up.

Comment: @scsimon Well it's the same [program] but the dates are different taht's why I have 4 row. I will rephrase my question, is there a way to group by [program] my 4 BMW's logos in a custom expression in labels with image rendering?

Comment: I think you'll need to post an image of your current graphic and tell us what the axis expressions are

Answer (score 0):

The is simply using the "Marker By : [ program ]" in the chart.